# While loop condition not working

Tags: c++

Well basically the condition for healthtwo causes the program to stop but not healthone for some reason

complete code: http://en.textsave.org/CmN

```
if (chance<=rando) {
   cout << " " << endl;
   cout << "Hit! Dealing " << attackp << " Damage!" << endl;
   healthtwo=healthtwo-attackp;
}
else {
       cout << " " << endl;
       cout << "Miss!" << endl;
}

chance=1+rand()%23;
if (chance<=rando) {
   cout << "Comp Used " << comattackname << "!" << " Hit!" << " Dealing " << attackcp << " Damage" << endl;
   cout << " " << endl;
   healthone=healthone-attackcp;
}
else {
   cout << "Comp Used " << comattackname << "!" << " Miss!" << endl;
   cout << " " << endl;
}


} while (healthone>=0 || healthtwo>=0);
```

Comment: Are you missing a "do" or something? Is this the complete sourcecode? If yes, it's no surprise that this doesn't work...

Comment: What's rando's value? And yes you seem to be missing a `do`, at least in your code sample here.

Comment: No its not the complete source code I am using a do. I just put the essential parts of the program.

Comment: `rando`'s value is definitely essential here.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a logical **and** (`&&`). After all, you want to check whether the health of *both* contestants is greater or equal to zero.

Comment: @user3144703: Your code (yes, I've read all of it), is currently too complicated and full of duplicates. For example your `move` and `comprandom` parts are almost the same. You should save the attack values and chances somewhere instead of using them as literals. That way it will a lot easier to change the values later.

Comment: @user3144703 If it works and solves your problem you should accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Wow Zeta thanks for the input! I really got to work on my efficiency and im currently working on implementing your improvements.